# MySQL Views versus truncate (or drop) and select into

Tags: mysql, view

I'm wondering if anyone has good stats on the performance of having views versus a script that deletes data, and inserts into temp tables.

So, as a very simple example, if we have a table of nationwide stores, and we wanted all the stores in California.  Instinctively I know that a view is the best way to achieve this.  However, I dont know MySQL well enough to say with 100% certainty that a view is much better than a script that truncates a table, and inserts all dealers from California. And the reason I bring it up is that in certain (more complex) situations, it seems that a script that does this, is sometimes faster than selecting from the view.

So, what I'm asking is basically if the overhead of creating a table, and populating it is less desirable to just creating a view in MySQL.

Comment: it can depend on database version ... can you provide us with your setup?

Comment: Are you saying you create a temp table, delete the rows from their original table then put them in the temp table? I assume you put them back... thats a lot more work then just making a view. Not to mention a lot more risker if something happens near the end of the process when you have to put the rows back if something happens and they havent been put back at that point they are lost.

Comment: Yes, but not even a temp table.  We have some scripts (that we inherited) that drop the table, then essentially create another table based off the old one (create table ca_stores as select * from stores), and run a script to truncate, and repopulate. What I'm trying to do is prove that the view performs better. In this case, I'm sure it does. Where I want to be certain is when you have joins with other tables. I think there it's case-by-case specific, but I wanted to see if views were pretty much the answer in 80% of the cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views can be tricky in MySQL.  For instance, they don't support subqueries in the `from` clause.

For most databases, I would advocate using views.  With MySQL, the situation is a bit trickier because you may not be able to readily express the queries that you want as a view.

There are certain advantages to using a temporary table.  You can add indexes as appropriate for a given query.  The size of the table is very well understood (if you happen to have a statistics-based query optimizer).  In some environments, the temporary database could be on faster disk than the original data.  And, the temporary table might fit into memory where the original wouldn't.  This could have a dramatic affect on the updates.

So, you might try a view to see if it works in your case.  It will not necessarily cover all situations, because of the limitations on views.  And, it is quite possible that the temporary table will actually perform better.

Answer (score 1):

Your phrasing suggests that you consider the option of extracting a subset of rows from the table (say) `stores` and copy it into a table (say) (say)`storesInCalifornia` *every time* you need the list of "stores in California". This options *may* be more expensive than a view, and useless at best.

I wrote "*may* be more expensive" because in fact it is possible that when reading from a view (or rather when combining records from a view with other tables or views), a temporary table is created internally (cf. [`TEMPTABLE` algorithm](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-view.html)).

I suppose you were rather thinking about a configuration where the `storesInCalifornia` is not reconstructed every time. A trigger on `stores` could synchronise the two.

This solution is probably preferreable and I guess it will perform better than a view on a regular table **for reads** (primary reason is, there are less rows in the table so indexes are smaller, and so on). Now you still need to determine if this gain is worth the negative impact on updates. This depends on the profile of your application usage, and there is no right answer.

Now there is a solution that combines the best of both worlds. [Partitionning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning.html). You could partition `stores` by state and/or country, and create a view on top of it. Only drawback (but a major one): partitionning [does not support foreigh keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-limitations.html).